# 2D Interpolation of data file

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

I hae a datafile with 5 columns of the structure:

```
x_i     f(x_i,y_1)  f(x_i,y_2) f(x_i,y_3) f(x_i,y_3) f(x_i,y_4)
```

with i = 1 to about 100. Thus there are about 100 lines, each corresponding to a different x-value, whereas each of the columns corresponds to a fixed y-value.

I want to interpolate on this 2D field and get f for arbitrary values (x,y). 
How do I bring this datafile into a form that Interpolation can work on it??

U.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, let say you have one `x` column and several `f[x,y]` column.

For example I assume `f1(x) = Sin[x]`,`f2(x) = Cos[x]` and `f3(x) = Exp[x]`.

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x], Cos[x], Exp[x]}, {x, -7, 7, .1}];
(*replace it with Import[file]*)
Do[f[i] = Interpolation[data[[All, {1, 1 + i}]]], {i, 3}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[i][x], {i, 3}]], {x, -7, 7}]
(*Replace 3 by the number of unknown `f[x,y]`*)
```

And each `f[i][x,y]` corresponds the interpolating function of the individual columns

[image]

> Example 2

Now I assume you know the `x` and `y` at which the data points are taken.
Let say you choose $y=(0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi /2, 2 \pi)$ and each of your column contains corresponding data. Let see with a trial function `Sin[x+y]`

```
f[x_, y_] = Sin[x + y]
xval = Range[0., 2. Pi, Pi/10.];
yval = Range[0., 2. Pi, Pi/2.];
data = Table[Join[{x}, Table[f[x, y], {y, yval}]], {x, xval}];
data1 = Flatten[Table[{xval[[i]], yval[[j]], data[[i, j+1]]}, {i, Length[xval]}, {j,Length[yval]}], 1];
g = Interpolation[data1]
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

`g[x,y]` is the function you want.

When you are importing data from a file, use

```
data = Import[file];
xval = data[[All,1]];
yval = {} (*write proper values*)
data1 = Flatten[Table[{xval[[i]], yval[[j]], data[[i, j+1]]}, {i, Length[xval]}, {j,Length[yval]}], 1];
g = Interpolation[data1]
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

And you will get your interpolating function.

**Corection**

Thanks to george2079 for pointing out my silly mistake. It would be `data[[i, j+1]]` in `data1`. As you can see the outcome is quite close now.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I had hoped there was an easier solution!
I still have a question on your example 2, which comes close to my problem: I read in the data file with the Import[file] command and then set xval and yval as you suggested. Now, what do I put in for f[x,y] in line 4 of example 2? simply replace f[x,y] by data (=Import[file])?

Comment: You don't need `f[x,y]` at all. I used it to produce the data. So you have to start from `data=Import[file]`, define `xval`, `yval` and then go to line 5 `data1=...`. Follow the last structure for data file. I wrote it completely now.

Comment: i think that should be `data[[i, j+1]]`

Comment: Thanks a lot @george2079. That was the culprit causing that ugly curve. You just make my day. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the other two answers are here, my input is somewhat redundant, but I feel, it's a good exercise in list manipulation and usage of mapping functions, so I'll leave it anyway.

Here's a solution, I feel is more readable.

First generate some fake data in your format:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x] Exp[y]
ylist = Range@4
list = Table[{x, Sequence @@ (f[x, #] & /@ ylist)}, {x, 0, 6.28, .01}]
```

Now `list` is the data in your format and `ylist` is a list of `y`-values, which in my example is simply `{1,2,3,4}`. Next break the data up into a list of `x`-values and a table of `f`-values:

```
xlist = list[[All, 1]] (* first column of the table *)
flist = list[[All, 2 ;;]] (* second thru last columns *)
```

Then pass a `MapIndexed` on the list of `f`-values as follows:

```
MapIndexed[{{xlist[[First@#2]], ylist[[Last@#2]]}, #1} &, flist, {2}]
```

In `MapIndexed` the slot `#2` stands for the position in the list, e.g `{100, 3}` meaning 100th row and 3rd column. We want to convert the data to a list with elements of the form `{{x_i, y_i} f[x_i, y_i]}` So we need to take the 100th value from `xlist` and the 3rd value from `ylist` (or other numbers, depending on the position in the table). That's exactly what the next line does.

```
{{xlist[[First@#2]], ylist[[Last@#2]]}, #1} &
```

`#1` stands for the actual value of the element at position `#2`. Then the result needs to be flattened, so

```
formattedlist = Flatten[%, 1]
```

and it's good to be passed to `Interpolation`.

```
fun = Interpolation[formattedlist]
Plot3D[fun[x, y], {x, 0, 6.28}, {y, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Compare to the function used to generate the fake data:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 6.28}, {y, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Looks like a good match.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this can be done with less fuss using `ListInterpolation`
( `data` and `yval` as from @Sumit's answer )

```
 g = ListInterpolation[data[[All, 2 ;;]], {data[[All, 1]], yval}];
 Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

> (* same plot *)

Better still, in this form if your `y` values are evenly spaced you don't even need to construct the list. Just give the range:

```
 ListInterpolation[data[[All, 2 ;;]], {data[[All, 1]], {0, 2 Pi}}];
```